# TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns, UTC] and datetime64

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime

Im trying to specifiy the timeframe in which I want to evaluate the csv data.

I thought converting the date I entered to `datetime64` using `numpy.datetime64` would solve the issue, but it seems `datetime64[ns, UTC]` is another format.

This is what I tried, and im getting the above error: Invalid comparison between `dtype=datetime64[ns, UTC]` and `datetime64`.

How can I convert the dtype to `datetime64[ns UTC]` or the other way around?

This is the code:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('/Users/youruser/Desktop/0b13c0f751243fda1229b7601db2c51c.csv', names=headers)

df['dt_iso'] = df['dt_iso'].map(lambda x: datetime.strptime(str(x), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z %Z'))


start_date = numpy.datetime64('2011-05-01T01:00:00.000000+0100')
end_date = numpy.datetime64('2012-05-01T01:00:00.000000+0100')
mask = (df['dt_iso'] > start_date) & (df['dt_iso'] <= end_date)

x = mask['dt_iso']
y = df['temp']
```

Thanks in advance!

Bonus question:

```py
df['dt_iso'] = df['dt_iso'].map(lambda x: datetime.strptime(str(x), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z %Z'))
```

What exactly does this line of code do? As far as I understand, it takes the Date information from the csv, makes a dtype object from it, then maps it to the dt_iso values. So is the unit of a datetime object `datetime64[ns UTC]`?

Comment: @bonus-question: it converts each element (string) in `df['dt_iso']` Series to a Python datetime.datetime object with given parsing directive. pandas then auto-converts Python datetime.datetime to its own datetime class, datetime64[ns] - or more specifically datetime[ns, UTC], if the input has a zero-offset from UTC (thus UTC is assumed). Since the lambda function is applied to each element in the Series, you end up with an iteration (in Python), which is inefficient given that you have a "vectorized" method for exactly that...

Answer (score 2):

Consider pandas' `datetime64[ns UTC]` to be an extension of [numpy's datetime](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.datetime.html) (`datetime64[...]`), that additionally allows to handle time zones. If one class has a time zone and the other does not, direct comparison is not possible. Even if you use pandas datetime consistently, either both datetime Series have to have a tz defined (be "tz-aware") or both have no tz defined ("tz-naive") - yes, UTC counts as a time zone in this context.

If you work with pandas and your input date/time for example represents UTC, you can [`.tz_localize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.tz_localize.html) to UTC, so that both Series in comparison are tz-aware.

In your example, you could use aware pd.Timestamps;

```
df['dt_iso'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dt_iso']) # simplify, does not require Py datetime

# use pd.Timestamps for comparisons
start_date = pd.Timestamp('2011-05-01T01:00:00.000000+0100')
end_date = pd.Timestamp('2012-05-01T01:00:00.000000+0100')

mask = (df['dt_iso'] > start_date) & (df['dt_iso'] <= end_date)
```

Comment: `1979-01-01 01:00:00 +0000 UTC` This is how the time information is stored in the csv. I tried the `to_datetime` method but unfortunately it doesnt work. It gives back a `dateutil.parser._parser.ParserError: Unknown string format: dt_iso` Maybe because of the string "UTC" still hanging on there  in my data?

Comment: @Tim: `Unknown string format: dt_iso` sounds like you try to parse the column title to datetime?

Comment: I deleted the column title just in case, but I still get: `dateutil.parser._parser.ParserError: Unknown string format: 1979-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC` using `df['dt_iso'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dt_iso'])`

Comment: @Tim yeah sometimes it's better to define the format explicitly, also to know exactly what the parser is doing... `df['dt_iso'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dt_iso'], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z %Z")`

Comment: it worked! Thanks, I've been struggling for months!